# jqplot - pass variable via ajax to C# page

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, jqplot

I am unable to retrieve values passed by $.ajax on my c# page.

I am using jqplot and I want to pass two pieces of information. One is stored in a  hidden field called 'hidden_plateid' and the second piece of information is from a dropdown box called 'SampleNumberList'

This is the hidden field

```
<input type="text" name="hidden_plateID" id="hidden_plateID" hidden="hidden" runat="server" />
```

And this is the drop down box:

```
<select name="SampleNumberList" class="DropDownBox_editjob" id="SampleNumberList">
    <option value="--SELECT--"></option>
    <option value="001r">001r</option>
    <option value="002r">002r</option>
</select>
```

I simply then say that everytime, someone selects from the dropdown box, to get and get the information from the db and plot the graph

```
$('#SampleNumberList').on('change', function (e) {

            var ajaxDataRenderer = function (url, plot, options) {
                var ret = null;
                $.ajax({
                    data: {
                        PlateID2: options.PlateID,
                        SampleID2: options.SampleID,
                    },
                    async: false,
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        ret = data;
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, err) {
                        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
                return ret
            };

            var jsonurl = "SpectraData.aspx";

            var plot2 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', jsonurl, {
                title: "AMIRA",
                dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
                dataRendererOptions: {
                    unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl, PlateID: $('#hidden_plateID').val(), SampleID: $('#SampleNumberList').val()
                }
            });
        });
```

I use Request.Querystring to try and retrieve the value in the c# file but so far, I get nothing

```
if (Request.QueryString["PlateID2"] != null)
{
   PlateID = Request.QueryString["PlateID2"].ToString();
}

if (Request.QueryString["SampleID2"] != null)
{
   SampleID = Request.QueryString["SampleID2"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve values from a query string , yet you are passing the parameters as json.
In order to retrieve them as a query string params, you need to pass them along your url.

```
$.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: url + "?PlateID2=" + options.PlateID + "&SampleID2=" + options.SampleID + "",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        ret = data;
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, err) {
                        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

In reality, the right way to do this is to pass params as a json string and intercept in the code behind.

```
$.ajax({
                                url: url/Somemethod,
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                  data: "{'PlateID2':'" + options.PlateID + "','SampleID2':'" + options.SampleID + "'}",
                                success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                            ret = data;
                        },
                                 error: function (xhr, err) {
                            alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                            });
```

In your codebehind :

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void Somemethod(string PlateID2,string SampleID2)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I have tried this but the value I get on the c# page is 'undefined'

Comment: I found out why. I needed to call PlateID using $('#<%=hidden_PlateID.ClientID%>').val()

Comment: Refer to the updated section. Use json objects to pass the data instead of request.query string